# Unable a call a Method created in src/test/resource

Tags: java, maven

I have created a simple Maven Project in which I have created a class under `src/test/resources`:

[image: launchBrowser.java in src/test/resources]

I have created a static method `chrome()` in the class `launchBrowser.java`.
But I could not call this static method in the class `testcase01.java` which is under `src/test/java`:

[image: testCase01.java in src/test/java]

Kindly advise on this.

Comment: Never put java files under `resources` and expect them to run.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: In general, java source files placed in the `src/test/resources` directory will never be compiled. See the [Maven Getting Started Guide](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html)

Comment: Why resources folder - Its not meant for class files

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak This is actually a case where images of code are acceptable. The core point of the question is not a problem in code but rather layout of the project. Which is easier to demonstrate with a screenshot.
The rationale of "no images of code" policy is that we could copy the posted code and play with it. This is not needed here.

Comment: Thanks @soufrk .... where should I need to place the class so I can make use of the methods in another class

Comment: @lexicore as long as they are in the question and not as links that are blocked by certain proxies

Comment: The why is simple. It a convention. This is one of the most important paradigms to follow. Convention over Configuration. This means follow the convention to put your production code into `src/main/java` your unit tests into `src/test/java` and properties which are needed in production code into `src/main/resources` and properties which are only for test code or which should overrule test production properties into `src/test/resources` this simplifies many thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Move your test source code to `src/test/java`.

By default, Maven will compile source code from `src/main/java` as "main" code and from `src/test/java` as "test" code. You can configure it otherwise, but you shouldn't.